# Finding a limiting matrix

Tags: matrices, markov-chains, stochastic-matrices

I am trying to find the limiting matrix for the indicated standard form.

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        .1 & .6 & .3 \\
        .2 & .2 & .6 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

I am confused because all of my examples in the text book have the top left section of the matrix as

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
Can anyone elaborate on this for me? Can I just carry on as normal with the matrix the way it is or am I totally misunderstanding how these things work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Markov chain seems to be absorbing: The probability to leave state 1 is zero, hence once you enter state one, you stay there forever. States 2 and 3 can access state 1, so after some sufficiently long time the Markov chain will end up in state 1 (and stay there forever). I would thus guess that the limiting matrix satisfies

$$
 \lim_{n\to\infty} P^n = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \cr 1 & 0 & 0 \cr 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$